# How to install a usb wifi adapter driver?

Tags: drivers, wireless, usb, internet, adapter

I have installed ubuntu running alongside windows 10. My usb wifi adapter works great on windows but not on ubuntu. I cant use the ethernet cable either because my port is broken. I have done some research but they all say to use internet which I cant do. My question is can I download the driver needed into an flash stick and install it on ubuntu, if so how can I do that?. 
P.s Im new using linux system.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can temporarily connect to Internet using e.g your phone.

Comment: How can I do that? Im using a desktop by the way.

Comment: Do you mean using it as a hotspot via usb?

Comment: You can connect your desktop to your phone and use internet to install drivers.

Comment: Either by USB or wireless tethering.

Comment: @Pilot6 will it work with ubuntu? I have done it on windows but never on ubuntu. Like I said I’m new to this.

Comment: Yes it will with no problem.

Comment: @Pilot6 It will have to be via usb because my desktop doesn’t pick up wifi. Thanks

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/s?rh=n%3A13983711%2Cp_36%3A1253503011&pf_rd_i=13983711&pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_p=8add31fb-36ce-5eb7-9492-590f67ac90cc&pf_rd_r=2V46WGT1JJXTSA36GTE7&pf_rd_s=merchandised-search-6&pf_rd_t=101&ref=Oct_UPriceC_13983711_SAll lists cheap Ethernet cards for your desktop

Comment: Start with https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-wireless-troubleshooting-hardware-check.html.en

Comment: Thanks guys, using my phone as a hotspot worked perfectly now i just gotta download the driver for my wifi adapter.